# Picard's theorem..how did they get this step?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here I have Picard's theorem and I don't understand the part of the answer which is in red...could someone tell me how they got it please ??

[image]

Comment: $f_y$ is shorthand for the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$, so $$f_y = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \Big(1 - ty\Big) = -t$$